# adding and deleting form rows with javascript

Tags: jquery, html

I created a form where add button **adds** another row with name, email and age in the form and **delete** deletes it.  However, jquery code does not work as intended. I am a beginner in jquery to figure out what mistake I have made. I looked through similar questions in Stackoverflow but could'nt figure it out.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var max_fields= 10;
     var wrapper  = $("#commentForm");
     var add_button = $("#addButton");
     var delete_button = $('#deleteButton')
     
     
     var x=1;
     add_button.click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      
      if (x < max_fields){
       x++;
       $(wrapper).append('<input id="bname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required/>', '<input id="bemail" name="email" type="email" required/', '<input id="bage" name="age" type="number" required/>' )
      }
     
     });
      $(wrapper).on("click","#deleteButton", function(e){
      
       e.preventDefault();$(this).parent('p').remove();
       x--;
      
      })
     
     
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <section class="container">
     <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="form-handler.html" autocomplete="">
     <fieldset>
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      
      <p>
       <span> Name </span> <br>
       <label for="aname" ></label>
       <input id="bname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required/>
      </p>
      <p>
       <span> Email </span> <br>
       <label for="aemail" ></label>
       <input id="bemail" name="email" type="email" required/>
      </p>
      <p>
       <span> Age </span> <br>
       <label for="aage" ></label>
       <input id="bage" name="age" type="number" required/>
      </p>
      
       
      <div class="input_fields_wrap">
      
       <div class="addButton">
        <button  type="button" value="add">Add</button>
       </div>
      
       <div class="deleteButton">
        <button type="button" value="delete">Delete</button>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      
     
     </fieldset>
     </form>
     
     </section>    
     
      
       
    
    </body>
```

Thank you.

Comment: this `bname` id will duplicated ID should be unique on context

Comment: your HTML has got some mistakes can you first fix them like capital `<P>` can not be closed with `<p>` just write all HTML in lower case. `</br>` is not a tag, is either `<br />`, `<br/>` or `<br>`

Comment: done. Thank you for spotting those mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are some things not good as you have them.

1. **ID**s should be unique
2. why use `<span>` if you have `<label>`
3. you can use `name="value[]"` put your eyes on the `[]` so if you submit your form you will get an array of values on the server which is just awesome
4. you need clean HTML! Cause yes upper- / lowercase does matter
5. if you have an ID the jQuery selector is `#` so `$('#my-id')` if you have a class it's a `.` so  `$('.my-class')`

Now I've changed it and tried to keep it simple so it should be easy to see whats going on.

1. Make a wrapper around those fields you want to copy / duplicate what ever. If they are the same as they are pretty much just copy that `<div>` and insert it
2. Removed all IDs (hope you don't need them) else you need to clean them up anyway.
3. use little CSS to hide the delete button at first field
4. insert delete button for every field, cause most users will click add multiple times, then insert data and then see they don't need all the fields so they want to delete the empty ones. Which is more simple if they can delete the single ones by one

Play with this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var max_fields= 10;
  var counter = 0;
  
  $('.addButton').on('click', function(){
      counter++;
      if(counter >= max_fields) {
          return;
      }
      
      var copy = $('.form-copy-wrap').first().clone();
      copy.find('.delete').removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#commentForm fieldset").append(copy);
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
      $(this).closest('.form-copy-wrap').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.delete[disabled] {
    display: none;
}

.form-copy-wrap {
    border: dashed 1px #afafaf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
    <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="form-handler.html" autocomplete="">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox"/>

<div class="form-copy-wrap">
        <p>
            <label for="aname" >Name</label>
            <input name="name[]" minlength="2" type="text" required/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="aemail" >Email</label>
            <input name="email[]" type="email" required/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="aage" >Age</label>
            <input name="age[]" type="number" required/>
        </p>
        <button class="delete" type="button" value="delete" disabled="disabled">Delete</button>
</div>

        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <div class="addButton">
                <button  type="button" value="add">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>



    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Delete with checkbox:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var max_fields= 10;
  var counter = 0;
  
  $('.addButton').on('click', function(){
      counter++;
      if(counter >= max_fields) {
          return;
      }
      
      var copy = $('.form-copy-wrap').first().clone();
      copy.find('input[name^="delete"]').prop( "checked", false );
      $("#commentForm fieldset").append(copy);
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
      $('input[name^="delete"]:checked').closest('.form-copy-wrap').remove();
  });
  
  $(document).on('change', 'input[name^="delete"]', function(){
      if($('input[name^="delete"]:checked').length >= 1) {
          $('.delete').removeAttr('disabled');
      } else {
          $('.delete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.delete[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.form-copy-wrap {
    border: dashed 1px #afafaf;
}

#commentForm .form-copy-wrap:first-child p:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
    <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="form-handler.html" autocomplete="">
    <fieldset>

<div class="form-copy-wrap">
        <p>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="delete" />
              Delete this row
            </label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="aname" >Name</label>
            <input name="name[]" minlength="2" type="text" required/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="aemail" >Email</label>
            <input name="email[]" type="email" required/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="aage" >Age</label>
            <input name="age[]" type="number" required/>
        </p>
        
</div>

        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <div class="addButton">
                <button  type="button" value="add">Add</button>
            </div>
            <button class="delete" type="button" value="delete" disabled="disabled">Delete</button>
        </div>



    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation as well. Makes it clearer to understand. However, I have a question if I want to add a checkbox so that when I want to delete the added boxes by ticking the checkbox and pressing the button"delete" instead of delete button in every new fields that is being added.can I do it by modifying this section in jQuery? $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){ $(this).closest('.form-copy-wrap').remove(); }); ofcourse i need to put the check box tag inside the div class"form-copy-wrap" tag. and also perhaps modify the delete button tag in html?

Comment: @BibekSharma updated the answer with checkbox delete. Makes a few things a little more complicated. Like what happens if user clicks the checkbox and then submits the form? Just things you should think about. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<body>
<section class="container">
    <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="form-handler.html" autocomplete="">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
          <div id="rows">
        <P>
            <span> Name </span> </br>
            <label for="aname" ></label>
            <input id="bname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required/>
        </p>
        <P>
            <span> Email </span> </br>
            <label for="aemail" ></label>
            <input id="bemail" name="email" type="email" required/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span> Age </span> </br>
            <label for="aage" ></label>
            <input id="bage" name="age" type="number" required/>
        </p>
        </div>

        <div class="input_fields_wrap">

            <div>
                <button id="addButton"  type="button" value="add">Add</button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button  id="deleteButton" type="button" value="delete">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>



    </fieldset>
    </form>

    </section>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var max_fields= 10;
    var wrapper  = $("#commentForm");
    var add_button = $("#addButton");
    var delete_button = $('#deleteButton');
    var rows  = $("#rows");


    var x=1;
    add_button.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if (x < max_fields){
            x++;
            rows.append('<p><input id="bname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required/>', '<input id="bemail" name="email" type="email" required/>', '<input id="bage" name="age" type="number" required/></p>' )
        }

    });
        delete_button.click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            $( "#rows p" ).last().remove();
            x--;

        })


    });


    </script>



</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is #rows added somewhere in the html file?

Comment: yes i put <p> inside <div id="rows"> you check the code. you will find it

Comment: i have updated the answer i have used id for buttons instead of class because you were accessing it like this $("#addButton") # is used for id and . is used for class

Answer (score 0):

You have very minor mistake in your code.

**Your Code:**

```
var wrapper  = $("#commentForm");
var add_button = $("#addButton");
var delete_button = $('#deleteButton')
```

It Should be like this

```
var wrapper  = $("#commentForm");
var add_button = $(".addButton"); 
/* '#' is used to refer ID, '.' is used for classes*/
var delete_button = $('.deleteButton')
```